# How to check the current logged user in the facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook

When the user clicks a custom button in my app, a content is published in the user facebook wall. My problem is when the facebook app is installed and the user login in the app the first time or the user is logged in the facebook app. When, I try to logout and login with a other account and execute my app. The app publishes in the facebook wall of the first account, not the second. How I can check the current user who is logged in the facebook app??

```
public void onCreateSMWDLoginFBByAccessToken() {
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(ShareFacebookActivity.this);

        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        openSessionForPublish(session);

    }
    onClickLoginFB();
}

public void openSessionForPublish(Session session) {

    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(ShareFacebookActivity.this);

    if (openRequest != null) {
        openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
        openRequest.setPermissions(ConstantsFacebook.PERMISSIONS_PUBLISH);
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
        session.openForPublish(openRequest);
    }

}

private void onClickLoginFB() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        openSessionForPublish(session);
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(ShareFacebookActivity.this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}

public class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        // REFRESH FACEBOOK STATE
        refreshStateSessionFB(session);
    }
}

private void refreshStateSessionFB(Session session) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {

        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, statusUserFB);
    }
}// end Method

public class SessionGraphUserStatusCallback implements Request.GraphUserCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

        if (user != null) {
            publishContent();
        }
    }// end OnCompleted
}// end Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LoginButton provided by Facebook to login/logout the user. The LoginButton in Facebook SDK3.0 has built in feature to change from login to logout once the user has logged in.

Comment: Is there another way to login and logout the user customizing the process. The problem is the design, I can't change it.

Comment: You can just keep your design as it is. You just need to change the images with your design images and edit some lines in the Facebook LoginButton class

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Facebook app and your app are completely independent, so when the user logs out of the Facebook app, your app has no idea. The only way to know is to log the user out of your app (by calling session.closeAndClearTokenInformation), and try the login again.

A recommendation is to always show the user's profile picture/name beside your post button, this way the person clicking the button will recognize that it's not their profile pic, and can then logout and log in as themselves.